# A question related to sound of Push Notification

Tags: iphone, audio, push-notification

1>I want to show a sound to user when push notification comes from user
  What should i do for that?

Comment: I'm sorry, but how do you 'show' a sound? And push notifications don't 'come' from the user.

Comment: First of all you should accept some answers. You have a reach history of questions with good but unaccepted answers.

Comment: I have done it what u said
Plz give me answer of this question

Answer (score 1):

After accepting the correct answers in earlier posts you should try to find an answer before posting a question.

Here is a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2180942/how-can-i-get-a-custom-sound-to-play-with-an-apple-push-notification)...

Just add a sound file and add its name to the JSON (as appears in the link above).